# Problems adding Date & Time values to a comparison using IF in a calculated column

Tags: column, comparison, date-time

I'm trying to compare a date by using `=if([Modified]<DATE(2012,2,8),"Outdated","Updated")` and it works just fine, but I have a problem with trying to add time to the comparison.

What I need is to compare an exact date and time. i.e. `=if([Modified]<"2/8/2012 10:30:30 a.m.","Outdated","Updated")` but don't know how to make it work. If the Item was last modified date&time less than 10:30:30 a.m. should be displayed as Oudated.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to compare a date by using =if([Modified]<DATE(2012,2,8),"Outdated","Updated") and it works just fine but I got the problem when trying to add time to the comparison.
What I need is to compare an exact date and time. i.e. =if([Modified]<"2/8/2012 10:30:30 a.m.","Outdated","Updated") but don't know how to make it work. if the Item was last modified date&time less than 10:30:30 a.m. should be displayed as Oudated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=IF([Modified<(DATE(2012,2,8)+TIME(10,30,30)),"Outdated","Updated")
```